# Existe problema de desempenho em utilizar muitas chaves estrangeiras (FK)? Se sim, é ruim ter atributos estrangeiros sem ser FK?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-estrangeira

Para esclarecer o quanto pode ser "muitas chaves estrangeiras", explicarei o contexto:

Em um sistema, quero armazenar por quem um determinado registro foi editado ( `updatedBy`) ou criado (`createdBy`). Isso pode acontecer por:

1. Um usuário, autenticado no sistema;
2. Pelo sistema, numa ação automática, por exemplo.

As tabelas (que hoje são 8, mas imagino essa situação em qualquer sistema) parecem algo como:

```
 _____________________________________________________
| ... | createdBy | createdAt | updatedBy | updatedAt |
|     |           |           |           |           |
|_____|___________|___________|___________|___________|
```

Pensei em três alternativas sobre **como** armazenar os campos `createdBy` e `updatedBy`:

1. Armazenar o nome do usuário;
2. Armazenar algum identificador do usuário, não necessariamente a chave primária, e sem criar chave estrangeira;
3. Armazenar a chave primária criando uma chave estrangeira.

Os **problemas** que eu vejo em cada alternativa:

1. O usuário pode mudar o nome, então o dado tornaria-se inconsistente;
2. Não me parece correto ter um atributo que funciona como chave estrangeira mas não é uma chave estrangeira, porém não tenho conhecimento para elaborar esse ponto e é a opção que estou utilizando agora (em ambiente de desenvolvimento);
3. Parece o modo mais correto, porém todas as tabelas teriam conexão com a tabela `Usuario` (inclusive ela com ela mesma), `createdBy` e `updatedBy` seriam **chaves estrangeiras opcionais**.

E então vamos às perguntas:

- Sobre a alternativa 2: Existe fundamento em dizer que é **ruim** utilizar atributos que funcionam como chaves estrangeiras mas não o são?
- Sobre a alternativa 3: Existe problema de desempenho em utilizar muitas chaves estrangeiras?

Se houver uma alternativa melhor que eu não tenha citado, com certeza agregará na resposta.

Caso a escolha do banco de dados seja relevante para a resposta (devido ao SGBD), estou utilizando MySQL.

Comment: "Existe fundamento em dizer que é ruim utilizar atributos que funcionam como chaves estrangeiras mas não o são?", você tem certeza de que quis dizer isto mesmo que escreveu? Se não são chaves estrangeiras é completamente errado qualifica-los como tal. É óbvio que o uso de chaves estrangeiras afeta o desempenho mas você terá um modelo mais robusto e com dados coerentes, resta a você avaliar o quanto isso é importante em seu sistema.

Comment: Esses atributos, na prática, não seriam FK, mas consultas seriam feitas como por exemplo `SELECT * FROM Usuario JOIN Roupa WHERE Usuario.username = Roupa.updatedBy`, foi isso o que quis dizer com "funcionam como chaves estrangeiras mas não o são"

Comment: Não me parece um requisito muito comum que precise ser guardado o usuário que criou/modificou um registro (e o que apagou também, pelo menos em muitos lugares isso é só marcado no registro, e não deletado efetivamente). Poderia dizer por que você precisa disso? A alternativa ao meu ver seria que o próprio schema já permita ter essa informação, dependendo de como ele é modelado.

Comment: Trabalhei em um projeto que resolveram desse jeito, então foi o jeito que "aprendi". Esse tipo de informação também seria exibido no *client*, em algumas situações, por isso imagino que precise estar no BD. Não entendo o que você quis dizer com "o próprio schema já permita ter essa informação", então não sei dizer se atenderia minha necessidade. Se tiver alguma referência pode compartilhar que eu leio :), ou se quiser montar uma resposta com isso, acredito que seja válido também como "uma alternativa melhor", conforme citei no fim da pergunta.

Comment: Eu diria pra criar uma tabela de auditoria, mover esses campos para lá e fazer FK para essa tabela de auditoria... No final das contas, sem um histórico, de nada servem estes campos...

Comment: @RafaelTavares Quis dizer a própria modelagem já indicar qual é o usuário que fez a modificação (em uma outra tabela, diferente daquela que tem o registro em questão). Mas não tenho um exemplo à mão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira opção realmente não é muito boa, mas há casos para uso. A segunda diminui o tamanho do campo mas tem o mesmo problema da primeira. Ela não garante a canonicidade da informação, mas pode ser feito manualmente.

A terceira costuma fazer mais sentido na maioria dos casos, mas não sabemos se faz no seu caso. Não temos detalhes, pode ser que isso tudo nem seja o mais adequado.

Haverá algum custo de performance em manter chaves estrangeiras, mas não costuma ser nada muito grande. Há casos que pode haver ganho, mas em geral só comparado com fazer o mesmo manualmente.

Em geral faz-se o que precisa, o que é mais correto, e se tiver problemas de desempenho começa fazer otimizações, se for possível sem prejudicar o funcionamento. Meça para tomar a decisão, não tome porque parece o melhor. Isso é otimização prematura porque o intuitivo nem sempre funciona, especialmente em bancos de dados.

Eu percebo que muitas pessoas estão preocupados com performance sem nem sequer chegar perto de isso ser um problema.

Se precisa da performance mais que qualquer outra coisa então faça o rápido e não se preocupe com outra coisa, mas isso pode complicar o desenvolvimento, nem todo mundo sabe lidar com isso para realmente deixar rápido. Não vá fazer manualmente o que o banco de dados faz automático quando tem FK, aí é pior.

Não é tão comum mas algumas pessoas preferem nem usar chaves estrangeiras e fazer validações só quando é necessário. Dependendo de como a aplicação é desenvolvida pode ser uma boa e uma otimização viável. Não é o fim do mundo não ter FKs, desde que saiba o que está fazendo.

Obviamente que eu parto do princípio que tudo está configurado adequadamente, principalmente existem índices adequados para facilitar a vida do SGDB verificar as tabelas estrangeiras. Não vou considerar o erro porque isso inviabiliza qualquer opção. Feito isso o custo é baixo.

Não existe receita de bolo que funciona sempre, sabendo fazer cada caso pode funcionar. Tem que entender o que acontece em cada situação, os compromissos de cada escolha dentro do seu contexto.